# VBA Excel Printing Array to Worksheet - Double Transpose

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I have a two dimensional dynamic array in my VBA code where the array dimensions are typically (1800,5) using option base 0. When I attempt to print this array to a range of 1801 rows x 6 columns on an Excel worksheet, I have to use the Worksheet transpose function twice. Any ideas why I have to do this and is there a better way of doing it without using the transpose function?

This code works;

`ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").[a1].Resize(UBound(MyArray) - LBound(MyArray) + 1, 6) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(WorksheetFunction.Transpose(MyArray))`

This code does not work;

`ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").[a1].Resize(UBound(MyArray) - LBound(MyArray) + 1, 6) = MyArray`

Answer (score 0):

Without using `Transpose`, here is a more robust method:

```
Dim numRows As Long
numRows = UBound(MyArray, 1) - LBound(MyArray, 1) + 1

Dim numCols As Long
numCols = UBound(MyArray, 2) - LBound(MyArray, 2) + 1

ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Resize(numRows, numCols).Value = MyArray
```

Comment: HI, thanks for this. It looks as if it should do the job but it doesn't work in my code and I'm now thinking that my array isn't the 2 dimension array that I think it should be.

Comment: I kind of guessed that was the issue :) Can you edit your question to include the array declaration?

Comment: My code is quite convoluted but I'm now pretty sure that I've got a 1D array of 1D arrays rather than a 2D array. Each item of the main array is the result of a SPLIT function.

Comment: All fixed now with a 2D array in place of the previous one and no transpose function. Many thanks for your help. It pointed me in the right direction.